# Coding / Database Pattern - Dismiss News

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application which has news that i can create in the database and display for my users. I want to provide users with the ability to "dismiss" a news article and never see the article again.  What would be a clever and sensible way to store / provide this functionality?

Some rough guidance would be great

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Add a flag(column) `IsDismissed in news table and if user dismiss the news then update value to `true` .. when selecting news data from db.. add condition `...where isdismissed='false'`

Comment: This wouldn't work for 2000 users..do i just need to have a join table of userid and newsid for dismissal?

Comment: Ok.. if you want `user specific` news feed dismiss track then the below answer is a great solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `User` table and an `Article` table, I'd suggest creating a many-to-many `UserArticle` table that contains a composite primary key of the User Id and Article Id, as well as a datetime field to record when the user has dismissed the article.

In your front-end code, when the user clicks the "dismiss" link/button, hook it up to a Jquery ajax call which calls a controller action which adds an entry to your `UserArticle` table with the current user Id, article Id and current datetime.

Then in your query that retrieves the list of news articles, add to the WHERE clause an additional clause that filters out articles dismissed by the current user.

Comment: Thanks for this...just what i needed.  Just didn't want to over engineer something!